# MySQL Query Error, thrown in PHP but fine in Terminal. Any Explanations?

Tags: php, mysql, command-line, terminal

**Edit:** This question is resolved. It was todo with other internal PHP code stripping out comments from the mysql query. The hash '#' in the string was getting treated as a comment starting point and from that point on the rest of the query was removed, thus resulting in a malformed query. But the profiler only traced the query before comments were removed.

---

I have this MySQL query:

```
INSERT INTO sacrifice_users 
(user_primary_role_id, user_password_salt, user_date_password_updated, user_password, user_login, user_visible_name, user_visible_name_urlsafe, user_firstname, user_lastname, user_email, user_date_created, user_status, user_date_edited)
VALUES
(6,'0(_!f\"}O:r1=Fsvb:Xb|0DG3S/gu&9K}/*5)7[2?30|V7+5<0;!f#)9o;bBc}@*/c\"q-@:8a{)0iY5?}5H7>550]QpS8Y[v(n@2|07)x-|-+-8242w?#4&+@/X:8,8Su','2011-02-02 15:02:18','MVYMGgXFqhM0grGWff9gctr2XPYhGD58IwBQ/aVITNbC9+odsm0eyF+fmyzb4qfes/Ij8hvY9yRVA3PZWzpxbMp8G43DgUhvYOUjqRYeHHfMcYPr7Uihh1hfAKQLS627','Admin','Admin','Admin','Admin','Admin','no-reply@xxx.co.uk','2011-02-02 15:02:18','confirmed','2011-02-02 15:02:18')
```

and it is throwing an error from MySQL in PHP

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''0(_!f\"}O:r1=Fsvb:Xb|0DG3S/gu&9K}/*5)7[2?30|V7+5<0;!f#)9o;bBc}@*/c\"q-@:8a{)0iY' at line 4

But running the query by the command line it runs fine. Anybody have any ideas as to why this might be?

Comment: You need to show the full relevant PHP line - chances are some of the data in the query needs to be escaped as it contains an embedded character that you're using to delimit the PHP string.

Comment: yes, this is most likely the issue

Comment: damn. just found the error. The hash '#'. There was php code that was removing comments from mysql but it was incorrectly treating the hash from within the string as a comment thus leaving a malformed query. my bad.

Comment: # cannot be an issue at all, because it's inside of quoted string

Comment: no it is the issue. See the edit at the top.

Comment: PHP code to strip comments from SQL? Genius. Brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

I see special characters. Can you try using [mysql_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to rule this out?

Comment: I do see that. I also think that it's wise to use standard helper functions that have been tested to catch all instances. A developer might be unaware of or glance over some when doing a manual insertion of escape characters.